# R: Trimming/ Setting Boundaries on Filled.contour plot

Tags: r, plot

I made a filled.contour plot and it cam out nicely, however I would like to trim out some of the hypotenuse of the triangle. Basically get rid of some of that yellow stripe along the hypotenuse. [image: Graph]

Is there anyway I could go about doing that in R?

Here is my code:

```
library(akima)
> attach(asc)
> 
> test<-interp(AvgDepth, AvgMaxDepth, Gs)
> 
> filled.contour(test, color=heat.colors, xlab="Depth (m)", ylab="Maximum Depth (m)", ylim=c(5,90))
```

Here is my data set

```
   AvgDepth AvgMaxDepth           Gs
1         5           5  0.022706473
2         5          15 -0.006287207
3        15          15 -0.002071806
4         5          25 -0.002569846
5        15          25 -0.005698020
6        25          25 -0.013394740
7         5          35 -0.001723604
8        15          35 -0.004575939
9        25          35 -0.001260225
10       35          35  0.025808307
11        5          45 -0.008369802
12       15          45 -0.004661506
13       25          45  0.003438334
14       35          45  0.004066056
15        5          55 -0.004517855
16       15          55  0.001577937
17       25          55 -0.000761080
18       35          55  0.004597452
19       45          55  0.015894575
20        5          65 -0.003023326
21       15          65  0.001327518
22       25          65 -0.000967222
23       35          65 -0.005843258
24       45          65 -0.000534109
25       55          65  0.001292299
26        5          75 -0.003593511
27       15          75  0.000484908
28       25          75 -0.008013139
29       35          75 -0.013281240
30       45          75 -0.009767021
31       55          75 -0.019364488
32       65          75 -0.019202670
33        5          85 -0.004487259
34       15          85 -0.001588138
35       25          85 -0.004464418
36       35          85 -0.007797982
37       45          85 -0.013272495
38       55          85 -0.022616793
39       65          85 -0.017740362
40       75          85  0.012021166
41        5          95  0.002236271
42       15          95  0.002102761
43       25          95 -0.001748743
44       35          95 -0.003063959
45       45          95 -0.001264025
46       55          95 -0.004662023
47       65          95  0.002980029
48       75          95  0.015868836
49       85          95  0.008842697
50       95          95  0.036387641
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: we can't use your data and how much do you want to remove? and why if I may ask?

Comment: The yellow color correspond to  `Gs > 0.02 & Gs < 0.035`. Remove those rows values from `asc`. Try this `asc2 <- dplyr::filter(asc, Gs < 0.02 | Gs > 0.035)`.

Comment: @MLavoie, Thanks for the reply. I'd like to tighten up the hypotenuse, and get rid of the boundary set to zero. If you look at the data, you can see that there is no point from x=60, y=60, yet the graph puts in a value, which is not accurate to the data. I would like to remove these points as it seems like the graph is filling in blanks.

Comment: @Narendra, Thanks for the reply. I don't want to get rid of the yellow specifically, but just get rid of that yellow streak that the graph seemed to have added but isn't represented in the data.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to do this?